# cannot cast from view to checkbox

Tags: android

ive been trying to build my app in eclipses workbench, however i have stumbled across an error message reading "cannot cast from view to checkbox". I have tried different things to resolve the issue to no avail, was wondering if someone could please help me out

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkbox;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
CheckBox pepBox, cheeseBox;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pepBox = 
            (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cheeseBox =
            (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    textView =
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}
```

that is the coding i have used

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="@string/pepperoni" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/extra_cheese" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onButton1Click"
    android:text="@string/show" />
```

that is my xml file
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That had me scratching my head for a bit.  I had to load your code into eclipse to find it.  Change `import android.widget.Checkbox;` to `import android.widget.CheckBox;`.  (Note the capital B in checkbox.)  Your code as posted works fine when I make that change.

Did eclipse not highlight the offending import?  Hovering the mouse cursor over a highlight will give you some clues how to fix it.  (forgive me if I sound patronizing.  Its hard to tell if someone with a low rep is new to the website or new to the platform)

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my problem. Its funny how such a small error can have you wondering for so long. No that is fine you did not sound patronizing at all, very helpful actually. And yes you are correct eclipse usually gives you hints on how to fix the problem, most of my other problems i fixed through the help of eclipses hints, however this particular error did not provide me with any hints. thanks again

Comment: For the future, that error would help us pinpoint the issue.  I often have to google the error message to find a clue as to what might be causing it.  Don't forget, the chances of you creating an error that no one has ever seen before are slim to nill.  Best of luck.