# Casting to checkbox from android.view

Tags: android

I`ve been trying to build my app in android studio workbench, however I have stumbled across an error message reading "cannot cast from view to checkbox". I have tried different things to resolve the issue to no avail.

This is mainactivity code:

```
 package com.example.sonu.animal;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Checkbox check1,check2,check3;
    private Button b1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addListnerOnButton() {
        check1 = (Checkbox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_dog);
        check2 =(Checkbox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        check3= (Checkbox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

This is xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.sonu.animal.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="dog"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_dog"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false" />

  <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cat"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox_dog"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:hint="cat"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="cow"
         android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
         android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:checked="false" />

       <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="select"
          android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I notice you instantiate the checkbox objects as `Checkbox`. Do you happen to have a class called `Checkbox` in your project? It may just be a typo in the question, but the class extending `View` is `CheckBox`, not `Checkbox`.

If this is not the issue, please let us know which of the calls is causing the cast exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot cast from view to checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480738/cannot-cast-from-view-to-checkbox)